# How to show open file dialog in sitecore content editor?

Tags: sitecore

I created a button and assigned command to it. Once user clicks the button open file dialog (<input type="file"/>) should be displayed. When file is selected it has to be uploaded to the server. So what is the fastest way to show open file dialog and get user input?

Comment: did you create button in content editor ?

Comment: Yes, I created it in core db under /sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Contextual Ribbons item and assigned to specific template.

Comment: What's the reason you want to implement such a functionality? Why don't you  upload files to media library?

Comment: I need to create a tree structure based on what is contained in uploaded .zip file. I can force content editors to upload zip to media library, but then Select Item Dialog should be displayed anyways. It seems easier to display common open file dialog.

Answer (score 0):

First upload in Sitecore is not straight forward. If we take the example of the Package Upload Form, we see that it makes use of 2 aspx pages. Moreover, when uploading on the CMS, it will store the information into the database.

**Possible Solution:**

Create an Upload Form which will appear when the user clicks on the button.
When user selects a file, you will need first to upload it before being able to have access to it. Once uploaded, you just need to read the Zip file in order to know the structure.

**Code Example:**

Check the `UploadForm.xml`. Path: `Website\sitecore\shell\Applications\Install\Dialogs\Upload package`

You will see the 2 aspx pages in the same folder. The codebehind is found in the **Sitecore.Client.dll**

Thanks